# Find an exact text inside an string with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with two columns, one for the ID and another one for Colors. Imagine that I have 3 lines in this table with the following data:

```
ID: 1 => Colors: Blue; Yellow; Red;
ID: 2 => Colors: Green; GreenYellow; Yellowgreen; Blue;
ID: 3 => Colors: Yellow; Blue;
```

If I want to make a SQL call to know if there is a register with yellow color (just Yellow, no GreenYellow or Yellowgreen). How can I do it? I´m trying with:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios  WHERE suscritos LIKE :suscritos");
$statement->execute(array(":suscritos" => "%Yellow%"));
$todos_mis_mensajes = $statement->fetchAll();
```

> IDs results: 1, 2 and 3

```
 $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios  WHERE suscritos LIKE :suscritos");
 $statement->execute(array(":suscritos" => "%Yellow_"));
 $todos_mis_mensajes = $statement->fetchAll();
```

> IDs results: No result

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios  WHERE suscritos LIKE :suscritos");
$statement->execute(array(":suscritos" => "_Yellow%"));
$todos_mis_mensajes = $statement->fetchAll();
```

> IDs results: 3

Comment: `(suscritos LIKE 'Yellow;%' OR suscritos LIKE '% Yellow;%')`

Comment: Worked! Create a response so I can validate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just put the exact "Yellow" word with no wildcards.

% indicates 0 or more characters.
"%Yellow%" indicates all strings with Yellow word.
"%Yellow" indicates all string that ends in Yellow.
"Yellow%" indicates all string that starts with Yellow.

_ indicates must have exactly 1 character.
"_Yellow" all strings that have a character before the Yellow word. 
ie: aYellow, bYellow
unacceptable: abYellow, Yellow

Answer (score 0):

Try this call:

```
select * from comentarios where suscritos regexp '[[:<:]]Yellow[[:>:]]';
```

Find more here about MySQL regular expressions:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html